# background audio playing works only once :issue in flutter ios

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc, just-audio, audio-service, get-it

I am using audio_service with just_audio in my app.when the app starts , they player is playing fine and the background also working fine.but when I enter to the app again(resuming the app).the player widget in the notification panel disappear and the background play stopped working.
what may be the issue ?

In console I am getting [**MRNowPlaying] Ignoring setPlaybackState because application does not contain entitlement com.apple.mediaremote.set-playback-state for platform**
and I am using FlutterVolumeController package as well.

My DI section is

```
setUpLocators() async{
  // common
  
  sl.registerSingletonAsync<AudioHandler>(() async => await initAudioService());
  sl.registerLazySingleton<ThemeBloc>(() => ThemeBloc());
  sl.registerLazySingleton<AuthBloc>(() => AuthBloc(
        useCases: sl<AuthUseCases>(),
      ));
```

Main method is

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  enableCrashlytics();

  /// setting the environment for production or staging.
  setEnv(EnvironmentType.production);

  setUpLocators();
  Bloc.observer = AppBlocObserver();
  setUpThemeChangeObserver();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

AudioHandler class is

```
Future<AudioHandler> initAudioService() async {
  return await AudioService.init(
    builder: () => MyAudioHandler(),
    config: const AudioServiceConfig(
      androidNotificationChannelId: 'io.exmple.audio',
      androidNotificationChannelName: 'name1',
      androidNotificationOngoing: true,
      androidStopForegroundOnPause: true,
    ),
  );
}

class MyAudioHandler extends BaseAudioHandler {
  final AudioPlayer _player = AudioPlayer();
  MyAudioHandler() {
    _player.playbackEventStream.map(_transformEvent).pipe(playbackState);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> playFromUri(Uri uri, [Map<String, dynamic>? extras]) async {
    mediaItem.add(MediaItem(id: uri.path.toString(), title: 'Sample'));

    _player.setAudioSource(
      HlsAudioSource(
        uri,
      ),
    );
    return;
  }

  @override
  Future<void> play() async {
    await _player.play();
    return super.play();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> pause() async {
    await _player.pause();
    return super.pause();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> stop() async {
    await _player.stop();
    return super.stop();
  }

  PlaybackState _transformEvent(PlaybackEvent event) {
    return PlaybackState(
      controls: [
        if (_player.playing) MediaControl.pause else MediaControl.play,
       
      ],
      androidCompactActionIndices: const [0, 1, 3],
      processingState: const {
        ProcessingState.idle: AudioProcessingState.idle,
        ProcessingState.loading: AudioProcessingState.loading,
        ProcessingState.buffering: AudioProcessingState.buffering,
        ProcessingState.ready: AudioProcessingState.ready,
        ProcessingState.completed: AudioProcessingState.completed,
      }[_player.processingState]!,
      playing: _player.playing,
      updatePosition: _player.position,
      bufferedPosition: _player.bufferedPosition,
      speed: _player.speed,
      queueIndex: event.currentIndex,
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> click([MediaButton button = MediaButton.media]) async {
    print('button===${button}');
    switch (button) {
      case MediaButton.media:
        {
          if (playbackState.valueOrNull?.playing == true) {
            await _player.pause();
          } else {
            await _player.play();
          }
          break;
        }
      case MediaButton.next:
      // TODO: Handle this case.
      case MediaButton.previous:
      // TODO: Handle this case.
    }
    return super.click(button);
  }
}
```

audioHandler is using in a bloc class as follows.

```
AudioHandler playerHandler = sl<AudioHandler>();

 await playerHandler.playFromUri(Uri.parse(
            'https://demo.unified-streaming.com/k8s/features/stable/video/tears-of-steel/tears-of-steel.ism/.m3u8'
           
            ));
```

**I have created a sample app with same code for audio service (only having dependencies audio_service and just_audio ) and it works fine for the background.I am not sure that any other dependencies in my project causing the issue. Please help me out.**

Comment: video or giff would be nice for this moment:'but when I enter to the app again(resuming the app).the player widget in the notification panel disappear and the background play stopped working.'.

Answer (score 0):

I was using flutter_volume_controller package and it was causing the problem.I replaced the package with volume_controller and it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: how did you notice that the reason is plugin exactly? How exactly did you understand this?

Comment: @VladyslavUlianytskyi I created a sample application only with just_audio and audio_service and it was working fine on background.and my app was using so many packages.other audio related package was this flutter_volume_controller.I added this to my sample app , and the problem occurred.so I replaced with volume_controller..works fine now. :-)